# Passing Java Function to KFunction

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, type-conversion, jvm

Is there any way way to pass a Function to method with parameters KFunction?
I have library in kotlin which I want to make work in java but I'm unable to convert Function to KFunction (?).
The function that I want to pass java function

```kotlin
// For example it will be in Event class
fun register(value: KFunction1<Value,Unit>) {
    ...
}
```

My tries to pass the function to kfunction

```java
public class Test {
    public void launch() {
        Event.register(Test::test); // Error
    }
    @Subscriber
    public static Unit test(Value data) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

PS. I need it to be KFunction due to usage of annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a Kotlin wrapper of the `KFunction`-accepting function, that takes a function type instead:

```
fun registerHelper(value: (Value) -> Unit) {
   register(value::invoke)
}
```

This can then be called from the Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public void launch() {
        registerHelper(Test::test);
    }
    @Subscriber
    public static Unit test(Value data) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

---

However, if `registerHelper` needs to access the name of `test`, or the annotations on it, rather than just call it, it is a lot harder.

One way I can think of is what you'd do in kotlin, when you want to convert a `java.lang.reflect.Method` into a `KFunction`. You'd use [`kotlinFunction`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/java.lang.reflect.-method/kotlin-function.html), right?

The `kotlinFunction` property corresponds to a static method called `ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction` in Java.

You can get the `test` method as a `java.lang.reflect.Method`, then use that to convert to a `KFunction`:

```
var testClass = Test.class;
var method = testClass.getMethod("test", Value.class);

// note the unchecked cast here, which is safe as long as you got the correct method
Event.register((KFunction<Unit>) ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(method));
```

Since the implementation of `getKotlinFunction` uses Kotlin reflection to find the function again, it might be better if you convert `Test.class` to a Kotlin class first, and then use Kotlin reflection directly.

```
var testClassKotlin = JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass(Test.class);
var kfunction = KClasses.getFunctions(testClassKotlin).stream()
    // use whatever criteria to find the method you want
    .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("test"))
    .findFirst().get();
```

---

That said, this is not how the Kotlin compiler internally makes a `KFunction`, when you write a function reference. The kotlin compiler actually creates a subclass of `kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl`. If you want to do what the compiler does, which I don't really recommend:

```
// yes, implementing the raw type of Function1 is necessary.
class SomeInnerClass extends FunctionReferenceImpl implements kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1{

    public SomeInnerClass() {
        // here you need to pass in the arty, declared class, name,
        // JVM signature, and some flags too
        super(1, Test.class, "test", "test(Lyourpackage/Value;)Lkotlin/Unit;", 0);
        // For what the flags mean, see 
        // https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/internal/FunctionReference.java#L16
    }

    @Override
    public Unit invoke(Object value) {
        return Test.test((Value)value);
    }

}
```

Then an instance of this is passed to `register`.